# React cannot use the updated Redux state after having dispatched an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm relatively new to React and Redux and learning them through my personal project.

The issue here is that `isAuthed` cannot use the updated Redux state after `rest.dispatch(actions.isValidUser(json))` is executed. As far as I know, the Redux state is updated by the action. (But I don't see `connect()` is called after the update...I don't know if this is associated with this problem.)

Also I tried using Redux-thunk in my action file to fetch data from an API endpoint and using useEffect(), but it didn't solve the issue. Could you please help me out?

Thank you in advance.

```
**ProtedtedRoute.jsx**

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/actions';


function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, isAuthed, ...rest }) {
  
  async function verifyUser() {
     // checking if a user is valid by checking JWT
      const res = await fetch(ENDPOINT, reqOptions);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const json = await res.json();
      rest.dispatch(actions.isValidUser(json));
    } else {
      // failure handling
    };
  };

  verifyUser();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => isAuthed == true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
    />
  );
};


export default connect(state => {
  return {
    isAuthed: state.isAuthenticated
  }
})(ProtectedRoute);
```

````
**reducer.js**
const initState = {
    data: {},
    // when a user is valid, it will be ```true```
    isAuthenticated: false
}
````

```
**App.js**

function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <div className="content">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <PublicRoute path="/login" component={LogIn} />
                <PublicRoute path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              </Switch>
              ...
```

```
**Login.jsx**

 const res = await fetch(ENDPOINT, { reqOptions});
        if (res.status === 200) {
            props.history.push('/dashboard');
        else{
            // error handling
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a function call like `verifyUser();` just floating in the component.  It needs to be inside a `useEffect` hook.

Your `Login` component fetches the endpoint before you redirect to `Dashboard`, so you should not need to fetch the endpoint *again* in order to access the `Dashboard` through `PrivateRoute`.

You can change your `initialState` to include `isAuthenticated: undefined` as in "we don't know if they are authenticate or not because we haven't checked yet."

Then in `PrivateRoute`, we only need to call `verifyUser` if the value of `isAuthed` is `undefined` meaning that we haven't checked yet.  If it's `true` or `false` we just use that existing value.

We still have a bit of a problem with the aysnc flow because we don't want to to `Redirect` off of the `PrivateRoute` before `verifyUser` has finished.  For that, we can conditionally render a loading state that shows while awaiting credentials.

I don't know that this is the most elegant solution but it should work

```
function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, isAuthed, ...rest }) {

  async function verifyUser() {
    // checking if a user is valid by checking JWT
    const res = await fetch(ENDPOINT, reqOptions);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const json = await res.json();
      rest.dispatch(actions.isValidUser(json));
    } else {
      // failure handling
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthed === undefined) {
      verifyUser();
    }
  }, [isAuthed]); //re-run when isAuthed changes

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthed === undefined ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : isAuthed === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```